# resampling date to calculate mean speed for each Driver on each 1 min than to count mean(speed)< 23 km/h

Tags: python, pandas-groupby, pandas-resample

i want add column to my dataframe to count for each driver mean(speed) < 23

this is my code to calculate mean(speed) on each 1 min and groupby driver

```
rawData.groupby('DriverId').resample("1T", on='time').SPEED.mean()
```

the result is :

```
 DriverId  time                     
0         2021-04-16 21:40:00+00:00     58.500000
          2021-04-16 21:41:00+00:00     32.850000
          2021-04-16 21:42:00+00:00     89.633333
          2021-04-16 21:43:00+00:00     88.166667
          2021-04-16 21:44:00+00:00    118.016667
                                          ...    
88        2021-04-27 07:30:00+00:00     79.566667
          2021-04-27 07:31:00+00:00     59.383333
          2021-04-27 07:32:00+00:00     89.133333
          2021-04-27 07:33:00+00:00     59.966667
          2021-04-27 07:34:00+00:00     25.724138
```

now i want add column 'lowSpeedEvent' to count how many mean(speed)<23

```
rawData.lowspeed=(rawData.groupby('DriverId').resample("1T", on='time').SPEED.mean() < 23).count()
```

the result is

```
rawData.lowspeed
15082
```

but i want to calculate foe each driver not a total for all drivers

Answer (score 0):

You can write something along the lines

```
rawData[rawData['Speed']<rawData['MeanSpeed']].count()
```

Comment: thanks i find my answer : ` rawData['lowspeed']=(rawData.groupby('DriverId').resample("1T", on='time').SPEED.mean() <23).count(True)